# caddy: one server, 2 secure reverse proxies

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I'd like to set up two secure reverse proxies on the same server with a single Caddyfile. The web server listens on port 8081, and the following successfully accepts outside connections on normal port 443 and directs them internally to 8081.

```
  # this works, accepting requests at https://api.mysite.com
  api.mysite.com {
    tls webmaster@mysite.com  # lets encrypt
    reverse_proxy localhost:8081
    log
  }
```

Now I want to also be able to connect to a database server that listens on port 7777, but I'd like to keep that port shut to the outside and accept incoming connections at port 9999 (over SSL/TLS). So far my attempts at building a Caddyfile have not just been unsuccessful, they also prevent the initial secure web connection from working.

(Caddy 2.4.3)

```
  api.mysite.com {
    tls webmaster@mysite.com  # lets encrypt
    reverse_proxy localhost:8081
    log
  }

  api.mysite.com:9999 {
    reverse_proxy localhost:7777
    log
  }
```

Nope

```
  api.mysite.com {
    tls webmaster@mysite.com  # lets encrypt
    reverse_proxy localhost:8081
    log
  }

  localhost:9999 {
    reverse_proxy localhost:7777
    log
  }
```

Nope

```
  api.mysite.com {
    tls webmaster@mysite.com  # lets encrypt
    reverse_proxy localhost:8081

     localhost:9999 {
       reverse_proxy localhost:7777
     }

    log
  }
```

Still nope

I'm having a very difficult time getting much useful information from the Caddyfile docs. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.